# Django listview doesn't show the recent data added to the database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

For some reason Listview doesn't retrieve the fresh data being added to the database. Here is my code:

```py
class UserThreadsListView(ListView):
    model = Thread
    template_name = 'tweetsview.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    context_object_name = 'threads_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context =  super(UserThreadsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        responsible = ConciergeSpecialist.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            context['teammates_list'] = ConciergeSpecialist.objects.all().exclude(active=False)
        else:
            context['teammates_list'] = ConciergeSpecialist.objects.filter(Q(org_unit_name=self.request.user.org_unit_name) & Q(active=True))
        context['responsible'] = responsible
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        responsible = ConciergeSpecialist.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        queryset = super(UserThreadsListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(tweet__responsible=responsible).order_by('id', '-tweet__created_at').distinct('id')
```

Then I use `{% for thread in threads_list %}` to iterate through the threads in my template `tweetsview.html`.

I can see the data in my database, however it doesn't get retrieved to the template for some reason. Only the old data that was retrieved the first time is showing up in a template properly. How do I fix this?

My Thread model

```
class Thread(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

Comment: Can you share your model definition? Is `Thread` attribute `id` unique?

Comment: Yes it is unique and it's the one assigned by django automatically. Added my Threads model above

Comment: Is it because you're paginating by 20 and not displaying the rest of the results?

Comment: I think it’s the matter of ordering but I don’t understand how to fix it. Newer items do appear bu at the end of the list :-(

Comment: With Django you need to make a new request (refresh) to get the data after you've added new data to the database. Unless you're rendering directly from the server. Are you using django templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering with:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['id']`
```

will order your model in ascending order. It sounds like you want them to be listed most recently created first. If this is the case use:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-id']`
```